# How to implement a contract for AAVE V3 "Supply, borrow, withdraw, loan etc" functsions

Tags: solidity, hardhat, defi, aave

I am trying to write a contract imported aave-v3 which includes the some aave v3 functions such as supply, borrow, repay etc. I will then make this contract accessible only to its owner.

For example:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity ^0.8.10;

import {IPool} from "@aave/core-v3/contracts/interfaces/IPool.sol";

contract AaveV3 {

     function supply(
        address pool,
        address asset,
        address onBehalfOf,
        uint256 amount
    ) public {
        IPool(pool).supply(asset, amount, onBehalfOf, 0);
        
    }

}
```

I don't understand what "address pool" is inside the supply function. I couldn't find any example contract defining these functions in.

Considering that I am inexperienced in this field, I am waiting for your help.

Comment: Please, can you clarify your issue?

Comment: I want to use aave-v3 inside my contract. To use some functions flash loan, borrow vs.

Answer (score 0):

Aave has a `Pool.sol` smart contracts which you can use to supply ,borrow .The pool address you are asking for is the address of the deployed contract on a specific network. For ETH mainnet it is here : [here](https://docs.aave.com/developers/deployed-contracts/v3-mainnet/ethereum-mainnet)